# Why is the output 321 instead of 212?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int k;
 
  for(i = 1, j = 0, k = 3 ; i <= 5, j <= 6, k > 1 ;i++, j++, k--);
  {
    printf("%d%d%d", i, j, k);
  }
 }
```

Why is this program printing 321 instead of 212?
I get 321 when I execute the program but I think it should be 212. I cannot understand why it is printing 321.

Comment: Did you use a debugger ?

Comment: No, I didn't use

Comment: The first thing you do when you run into a problem should be to debug your program and go through it step by step. Here you would have figured what is happening just by seeing the `printf` is not being executed inside the loop.

Comment: `i <= 5, j <= 6, k > 1` What is this condition supposed to mean? I am rather sure it does not do what you think it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have a semicolon at the end of the `for` loop, so the code runs essentially like this:

```c
// first you increment i,j and decrement k until k is 1, so twice
for(i = 1, j = 0, k = 3 ; i <= 5, j <= 6, k > 1 ;i++, j++, k--) {}
// then you print the values
printf("%d%d%d", i, j, k);
```

Comment: But as k becomes 1, condition k > 1 is false. So does not the loop end when k = 2 ?

Comment: The loop will exit when `k` is not greater than `1`, that is when it is exactly `1` in our case. Each iteration first checks the condition and then runs the body.

Comment: Ok. I got it now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Decent compilers will warn against such semicolons. Decent coding standards outlaw the practice and force you to either use `{}` or place the semicolon on a line of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 bugs.

The first was already mentioned and should also be reported by your compiler.
You have a stray semicolon after your `for` loop.

The second is that your condition is rather strange: `i <= 5, j <= 6, k > 1`
Relational operators have higher precedence than coma operator. That means this condition is same as `(i <= 5), (j <= 6), (k > 1)` which again is same as `k>1`.
If you want to have all the relational operands evaluate to `true`, you must add logical operator: `i <= 5 && j <= 6 && k > 1`